# View thread created by a app compiled by g++ in Windows

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, cygwin

I created a simple C++ multi-threaded program using g++ under Cygwin in Windows.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>         // std::thread
using namespace std;

void thread_func(void)
{
    sleep(20);
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(thread_func);
    thread th2(thread_func);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
}
```

I am guessing the threads are implemented in some Windows library, using Windows native thread.  And guessing that is why they don't show in "ps" or "ps -W" when run in cygwin.  I only see one entry, when I a expecting three.

Is there some other tool I can use in cygwin or native windows tools to get the complete list of threads?

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` shows processes not threads.
You can use strace; assuming your program is `thread.cpp`

```
g++ -ggdb thread.cpp -o thread
strace -o thread.strace thread.exe
```

you can see when the threads where initiated at `pthread::thread_init_wrapper`

```
$ grep thread thread.strace
--- Process 7404 thread 7840 created
--- Process 7404 thread 8804 created
--- Process 7404 thread 8920 created
--- Process 7404 thread 8004 created
  635 4552571 [ldap_init] t 7404 cygthread::stub: thread 'ldap_init', id 0x1F44, stack_ptr 0xC1CCD0
--- Process 7404 thread 4364 created
  400 9133089 [t] t 7404 pthread::thread_init_wrapper: tid 0xFFDFCE00
--- Process 7404 thread 5740 created
  340 9133541 [t] t 7404 pthread::thread_init_wrapper: tid 0xFFBFCE00
--- Process 7404 thread 4364 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 7404 thread 5740 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 7404 thread 8804 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 7404 thread 7840 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 7404 thread 1328 exited with status 0x0
--- Process 7404 thread 8004 exited with status 0x0
```

You can also use gdb but it is a bit more complicated.